# How to write unit test cases for a function in typescript jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have created a sample project. There I am writing a unit test case for functions on click.
I have created jest function for two. Below is my testing file.

```
const increaseAge = jest.fn();
const decreseAge = jest.fn();

const mockProps = {
    age: '20',
}

it('function called when increase age is clicked', () => {
        const render = mount(<Provider store={store}><Age {...mockProps} /> </Provider>);
        const increaseButton = render.find('[className*="btn btn-success"]').first();
        expect(increaseButton.text()).toBe("Increase Age");
        render.find('[className*="btn btn-success"]').first().simulate('click');;
        expect(increaseAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
        render.unmount();
      });
```

I am getting error in toHaveBeenCalled. Exoected should be >=1 but received is 0.
Below is my component code -

```
const increaseAge = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(ageUp(1))
    }
<button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={increaseAge}>Increase Age</button>
```

Onclick I will dispatch a action. How can I resolve this issue & dispatch an action ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in your test you never insert the mocked version of increaseAge into your component.

You probably don't want to test increaseAge directly, but instead want to test that the component will dispatch the right action.

You could do that by giving it dispatch as a prop, so you can mock it for your tests. Or you could use something like [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store) to mock your store.